# Linq To DataSet getting error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-dataset

In my WinForm project, I try to access to the table in DataSet with help of LINQ.

```
      DSObjectData lDataSetObject; // DSObjectData -Strongly typed DataSet

       var q = from contour in lDataSetObject.Contour
               select contour;
```

But on **select** operator I get this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a
>   delegate type

Comment: Is the `Contour` `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTable is not Enumerable.

```
var q = from contour in lDataSetObject.Contour.AsEnumerable()
               select contour;
```

`q` is `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

Comment: No, it is not enumerable. What you want to enumerate in DataSet?

Comment: I want to enumerate DataTables in DataSet